# Is it possible to print the sum of negative integers without using array or loop in C program?

Tags: c

Our activity requires to input 4 numbers, positive or negative and only add the negative numbers.

Example:

```
-30.22
10.50
-2.2
-1.8
```

Result is `-34.22` which sums up the negative numbers only.

We have not discussed the loop or array at this moment. Is it possible to solve in a mathematical equation? I can’t seem to find any answers if I try to code it.

Can it be solved using if-else-elseif statements?

Comment: Those aren't integers, they're floating point numbers.

Comment: Integers don't have fractions after the decimal point.

Comment: If the number of inputs is always 4, you can simply read them into 4 different variables, then use 4 `if` statements. No array, no loop.

Comment: Sorry, yes. They’re floats. Bub is possible to solve them without using array or loop? Most of the tutorials that I see online, uses loop or array but we haven’t discussed that yet

Comment: If you want it in a single expression you can use a ternary `+ (input1 < 0 ? input : 0)`

Comment: Yes, I just said how to do it. Do you really need a tutorial to tell you how to write an `if` statement?

Comment: Sorry ‘bout that. It’s. It’s not reflecting real time here on my end. Yes, I do know how to write if statements. But the thing is, they gave us a hint that if -else -else if statements isn’t needed to solve it. But if you say so, I’ll just try it using the if statements.

Comment: Seems like they are trying to have us solve a problem that doesn’t have an answer if the “if” statements isn’t needed. Haha

Comment: You can also do it with ternaries as I showed above, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thing is, it wasn’t even discussed what the ternaries are but I’ll just search it online.

Comment: Usually assignments are meant to reinforce a lesson that was just taught. What was the lesson about?

Comment: Thanks for helping out man! I can have this discussed tomorrow in our class tomorrow that without those, it is impossible.

Comment: @Charles I'd really be curious what your teacher _actually_ had in mind. Please answer your own question as soon as this has been discussed in your class.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sure man. I’ll update this one once I have this discussed or solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the input into four variables, then use four `if` statements to add them to the total when they're negative.

```
float a, b, c, d;
scanf("%f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
float total = 0;
if (a < 0) {
    total += a;
}
if (b < 0) {
    total += b;
}
if (c < 0) {
    total += c;
}
if (d < 0) {
    total += d;
}
printf("%.2f\n", total);
```

You can also use the conditional operator.

```
float total = (a < 0 ? a : 0) + (b < 0 ? b : 0) + (c < 0 ? c : 0) + (d < 0 ? d : 0);
```

Comment: Thanks man! I’ll try this one. I appreciate it!

Comment: This is great answer man. Substitution. So if is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

These assignments some teachers invent are really pathetic.

Maybe you want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float a, b, c, d;
  scanf("%f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
  float total = (a < 0 ? a : 0) + (b < 0 ? b : 0) + (c < 0 ? c : 0) + (d < 0 ? d : 0);
  printf("%f", total);
}
```

No loops, no if/else.

But be aware that this is really terrible code.

Comment: They apparently haven't learned ternaries, either. I'm not sure what the teacher is expecting them to use.

Comment: @Barmar nor am I. Read my last comment to the question

Comment: @Barmar I'll probably delete this answer, but for the moment I keep it in case you want to add further comments

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks man! I appreciate this one. I’ll study what ternaries are so that I can understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution that doesn't use neither `if` nor `while` (and co.)

```c
int main(void) {
  float n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0, n4 = 0;

  printf("Insert first number: ");
  scanf("-%f", &n1);
  scanf("%*[^\n]");

  printf("Insert second number: ");
  scanf(" -%f", &n2);
  scanf("%*[^\n]");

  printf("Insert third number: ");
  scanf(" -%f", &n3);
  scanf("%*[^\n]");

  printf("Insert fourth number: ");
  scanf(" -%f", &n4);
  scanf("%*[^\n]");

  float sum = -n1 - n2 - n3 - n4;

  printf("Sum of all negative numbers: %f\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation

`scanf("-%f", &n1)` will have two possible behaviors:

- in case of positive numbers (e.g.: `3.14` or `+1.2`), it will fail to parse the input (because it isn't able to match the first `-` symbol), so variable `n1` stays `0`;
- in case of negative numbers (e.g.: `-5` or `-3.1`), it will match the minus symbol and put the rest of the number into `n1` (so `n1` is either `5` or `3.1`, for instance).

Basically, for all four numbers, if the user input is positive, `n` is `0`; if the input is negative, `n` is the absolute value of the number (`2.0` instead of `-2.0` etc).

`scanf("%*[^\n]")` will clear the input buffer after (possible) positive numbers (because `scanf()` won't match positive numbers).

`float sum = -n1 - n2 - n3 - n4` is a (weird) "sum", but necessary since all four numbers are either `0` or the negation of a negative number.

---

#### DISCLAIMER

This answer is considered **bad practice** and its technique should never be used in real programs. The only purpose of this answer is to prove that there exists a solution to OP's problem that doesn't use loops nor conditionals. Every C programmer should however use loops and/or conditionals to make their code cleaner and safer (look at the other answers for a "good" solution).

Comment: This kind of nonsense shouldn't be teached. But I admit the solution is creative, so I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Jabberwocky My answer is not nonsense, my answer is *total trash*. But it *does* answer OP's question (a solution without loops and, possibly, conditionals). So the purpose of my answer was to prove that a solution without `if`s is possible. P.S.: I added a disclaimer to my answer to make this clear. Thanks for pointing it out, anyway.